# Get the information in terms of time about people who are free on a particular day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
(
     ID varchar(10),
     StudentName varchar(30), 
     Course varchar(15),
     SECTION varchar(2),
     DAY varchar(10),
     START_TIME time, 
     END_TIME time, 
     actual_starttime time, 
     actual_endtime time
);

INSERT INTO Table1 
VALUES (111, 'Mary', 'Science', 'A', 'Mon', '13:30:00.0000000', '16:20:00.0000000', '09:00:00.0000000', '21:20:00.0000000')
INSERT INTO Table1 
VALUES (111, 'Mary', 'Maths', 'A', 'Tue', '12:30:00.0000000', '13:20:00.0000000', '09:00:00.0000000', '21:20:00.0000000')
INSERT INTO Table1 
VALUES (111, 'Mary', 'Physics', 'C', 'Tue', '10:30:00.0000000', '11:10:00.0000000', '09:00:00.0000000', '21:20:00.0000000')
INSERT INTO Table1 
VALUES (112, 'Robert', 'Maths', 'A', 'Mon', '13:30:00.0000000', '16:20:00.0000000', '09:00:00.0000000', '21:20:00.0000000')
```

The scenario is as follows: the student can have class from morning 9 to night 9:30 from Monday to Friday. My requirement is I have to identify a timeslot where all the students in the same section are free so that a teacher can reschedule a class.

Example: both Mary and Robert are free in the morning from 9:00 to 1:30 in the afternoon on Monday. I would like to write query for this.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to write down the query but got nothing out of it..can you help me with the logic..

Comment: Please share your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return the full list of the timeslots available, you need to build a set of all the timeslots for each day of the week and then find if any of these slots have students being taught within it.

This is easily achieved with a recursive CTE to build your full timeslot set, from which you can JOIN into your Students data.  The output of the query below is the day and time of each vacant session:

```
-- Build the dummy data sets:

declare @Data table
(
     ID varchar(10),
     StudentName varchar(30), 
     Course varchar(15),
     SECTION varchar(2),
     DAY varchar(10),
     START_TIME time, 
     END_TIME time, 
     actual_starttime time, 
     actual_endtime time
);

insert into @Data values
 (111, 'Mary', 'Science', 'A', 'Mon', '13:30:00.0000000', '16:20:00.0000000', '09:00:00.0000000', '21:20:00.0000000')
,(111, 'Mary', 'Maths', 'A', 'Tue', '12:30:00.0000000', '13:20:00.0000000', '09:00:00.0000000', '21:20:00.0000000')
,(111, 'Mary', 'Physics', 'C', 'Tue', '10:30:00.0000000', '11:10:00.0000000', '09:00:00.0000000', '21:20:00.0000000')
,(112, 'Robert', 'Maths', 'A', 'Mon', '13:30:00.0000000', '16:20:00.0000000', '09:00:00.0000000', '21:20:00.0000000');



-- Query the data:

with TimeSlots as   -- Recursive CTE builds a table of all timeslots in TIME data type.
(
    select cast('09:00:00' as time) as TimeSlotStart
            ,cast('09:30:00' as time) as TimeSlotEnd
    union all
    select dateadd(minute,30,TimeSlotStart)
            ,dateadd(minute,30,TimeSlotEnd)
    from TimeSlots
    where TimeSlotStart < cast('21:00:00' as time)
)
, TeachingDays as   -- Used to return all the time slots above for each day of the week in CROSS JOIN below.
(
    select 1 as DaySort
        ,'Mon' as TeachingDay
    union all
    select 2 as DaySort
        ,'Tue'
    union all
    select 3 as DaySort
        ,'Wed'
    union all
    select 4 as DaySort
        ,'Thu'
    union all
    select 5 as DaySort
        ,'Fri'
)
select td.TeachingDay
        ,t.TimeSlotStart
        ,t.TimeSlotEnd
from TimeSlots t                    -- Select all timeslots.
    cross join TeachingDays td      -- For each day.
    left join @Data d               -- And find all students that are being taught on that day at the specified time.
        on(td.TeachingDay = d.DAY
            and t.TimeSlotStart <= d.END_TIME
            and t.TimeSlotEnd > d.START_TIME
            )
where d.ID is null                  -- Then only return data where there are no students being taught at this timeslot.
order by td.DaySort
        ,t.TimeSlotStart;
```

Comment: left join @Data d               -- And find all students that are being taught on that day at the specified time.
        on(td.TeachingDay = d.DAY
            and t.TimeSlotStart <= d.END_TIME
            and t.TimeSlotEnd > d.START_TIME
            )

Comment: @SindhuB  Are you saying that you still don't understand it or that it took you a while to work out why it works?

Comment: i said that it took time for me to figure out the logic before and failed on that part. Your logic is pretty understandable and it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Stored Procedure with following steps.

Step 1: Predefine timeslots in a different table.(09:00-10:00, 10:00-11:00 etc)

Step 2: Select count of students

Step 3:

```
for all the slots
     Begin
           for all the students
          Begin
              if(students.actual_starttime =slots.actual_starttime and 
                 students.actual_endtime =slots.actual_endtime
              break;
             else count=count+1;
          End
     End
```

Step 4: if above count matches with count of total students, then slot is free for all the students else slot is not foree for all the students.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you find difficulty with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have three more tables to make it more simple
i.e. Student, Section and slots

I tried to create 1 more table with half hour slots

```
create table table2(timeslot time);

insert into table2 values ('9:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('9:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('10:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('10:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('11:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('11:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('12:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('12:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('13:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('13:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('14:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('14:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('15:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('15:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('16:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('16:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('17:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('17:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('18:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('18:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('19:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('19:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('20:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('20:30:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('21:00:00.0000000');
insert into table2 values ('21:30:00.0000000');
```

Following SQL will give you free slot and name of student:

**Query:**

```
select t1.StudentName,t2.timeslot
from Table2 t2,
Table1 t1
where t2.timeslot<t1.start_time
and t2.timeslot<t1.end_time
and t1.section='A'
group by t1.StudentName,t2.timeslot
order by t2.timeslot
```

**Output:**

```
    StudentName timeslot
1   Mary    09:00:00
2   Robert  09:00:00
3   Mary    09:30:00
4   Robert  09:30:00
5   Mary    10:00:00
6   Robert  10:00:00
7   Mary    10:30:00
8   Robert  10:30:00
9   Mary    11:00:00
10  Robert  11:00:00
11  Mary    11:30:00
12  Robert  11:30:00
13  Mary    12:00:00
14  Robert  12:00:00
15  Mary    12:30:00
16  Robert  12:30:00
17  Mary    13:00:00
18  Robert  13:00:00
```

This is just half task done, I just showed you way to achieve it. Introduce two more joins with student and section table to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Shred the day (09:00 to 21:30 interval) into minutes, find free minutes with respect to students of the group and days of interest and group minutes found back as intervals.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (ID varchar(10),StudentName varchar(30), Course varchar(15) ,SECTION varchar(2),DAY varchar(10),
START_TIME time , END_TIME time, actual_starttime time, actual_endtime time);

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (111, 'Mary','Science','A','Mon','13:30:00.0000000','16:20:00.0000000','09:00:00.0000000','21:20:00.0000000')
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (111, 'Mary','Maths','A','Tue','12:30:00.0000000','13:20:00.0000000','09:00:00.0000000','21:20:00.0000000')
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (111, 'Mary','Physics','C','Tue','10:30:00.0000000','11:10:00.0000000','09:00:00.0000000','21:20:00.0000000')
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (112, 'Robert','Maths','A','Mon','13:30:00.0000000','16:20:00.0000000','09:00:00.0000000','21:20:00.0000000')
;

-- parameters

declare @tds time = '09:00';
declare @tde time = '21:30';

declare @section varchar(2) = 'A';

create table #daysofinterest (DAY varchar(10) primary key);
insert  #daysofinterest (DAY) values ('Mon'),('Tue'),('Fri');

create table #groupmembers(ID int primary key);
insert #groupmembers(ID) values (111),(112);

-- query
select DAY, startt = dateadd(minute, min(n), @tds), endt = dateadd (minute, max(n), @tds)
from (
    select DAY, n, grp = n - row_number() over(partition by DAY order by n) 
    from (
      -- all minutes of the day, @tds till @tde
      select top (datediff(minute, @tds, @tde)) n = row_number() over(order by (select null))
      from sys.all_objects 
    ) tally
    cross join #daysofinterest dd
    join #groupmembers gm on
       not exists (select 1 from table1 t 
                   where t.ID = gm.ID and t.DAY = dd.DAY and SECTION = @section and
                   dateadd (minute, n, @tds) between t.START_TIME and t.END_TIME )

    group by DAY, n
    --this minute is free for every group member
    having count(*) = (select count(*) from #groupmembers)
) g
group by DAY, grp
order by DAY, min(n)
```